# Angular canvas not defined in ngAfterViewInit?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I encountered a strange error while working with angular. How is it possible that an element is not defined   `ngAfterViewInit()` function, is not this the function that is actually called when all html has been loaded , Im getting error "Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined"? Any ideas would be appreciated. Here is the html:

```
<div *ngIf="loading">
<img src="../../assets/loading.gif" alt="Loading data" 
style="width:64px;height:64px;">
</div>
<div *ngIf="!loading">
<div style=" width:auto; margin-top:30px;" >
  <div *ngIf="users">
<h1>Edit User</h1>

<div class="fluid centered">

<canvas #cns width="240" height="240"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and in component.ts:

```
@ViewChild("cns") cns: ElementRef; // DECLARED AT THE BEGINING

ngAfterViewInit() {
let self = this;
let canvass: HTMLCanvasElement = this.cns.nativeElement; // error
}
```

Comment: If `loading` is true or if `users` is falsy, the canvas is not present on the page. You can check these values in `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: Oh yes, forgot about that. It made sense to me that even if that is not true, the html should still be loaded. this is probably the  right way.

Comment: An alternative is to use `[hidden]="!condition"`, which keeps the element in the DOM, but hides it.

Comment: By the way, my first comment was meant to explain why the canvas is not present. If you really need to protect your code for these cases, you can just check if `this.cns` is defined.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, needed to use [hidden], otherwise it was not defined in the proper time. Thank you both!

Comment: Misread the author of the second comment. Let me correct my statement: Thank You!!